# no output when .jar is executed

Tags: java, r, jar, jri

I built an application in Netbeans 6.8 and made **project.jar** file. When I run it, it **works only on my computer**, but not on any other computer. However, when I made any simple application, that doesnt use any libraries, it works fine on any computer. 
Is there any way, how to invoke some error message, where is the problem?

My project use R 2.9.2, so I install this version on other computer and set the System Path variable exactly same. Other libraries listed in lib directory are: AbsoluteLayout.jar,DatePicker-V0.99-2006.09.01.jar,jcommon-1.0.16.jar,jfreechart-1.0.13.jar,jmathplot.jar,JRI.jar,pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar

Thank you

Comment: do you rely on the system CLASSPATH variable? if you do, stop doing that. As that is an endless supply of these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get any message at all?  What do "works" and "not works" look like?

You sound like another person who hasn't taken the time to learn how to do things by hand on the command line without an IDE.  I'd recommend doing that.  Open a command shell and type in the `java -jar -cp ... foo.jar` command to run your stuff.  The messages you get back will be educational.

Note the `-cp` command line argument.  That's how you add your JARs to the CLASSPATH properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows, maybe it will help someone.I add 2 paths in PATH system variable:
Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced 
Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH.
you must add both paths, to jri.dll and r.dll, in my case it were these:
C:/Program Files/R/R-2.9.2/bin/;C:/Program Files/R/R-2.9.2/library/rJava/jri/;
I have added these lines already, but with different different slash. **So be careful, you must use it /  not \ to define path!!!**